# onEdit custom selection of edited range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-query

Data gets posted from an external source to my spreadsheet. The data range is across three columns - A, B, C. I can access the newly modified range using the onEdit script.

```
function onEdit(e){
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();

  if(activeSheet.getName() !== "Raw") return;
  var range = e.range;
```

However, I want to modify range such that it only contains the range values from column B. Is there an easy way to filter out the other values or not select them in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not the getColumn function you need. You can use the `getRange(a1Notation)` method, then get the value of that range.

I've linked the method from the developer.google sight for that method [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRange(String)).

UPDATE:
Based on the comment feedback, if there is always just the three columns, you'd use

```
var range = e.range;
var data = range.getValues(); //returns row as an array
var cell = data[0][1]; //gets data for column B, then you can do whatever with  it
```

getValues() returns a 2D array, so if you have more than one row, you'll need to use a double for loop or something that gets the same effect to iterate through them.

Comment: I can't use `getRange` on a range?

Comment: Ah, I see the problem now.

Comment: @EndaMolloy I updated my answer based on my new understanding of your question. This should get you the value you're looking for.

Comment: Good job Randy, I managed to solve it once I started thinking in terms of arrays. I can get away with a single for loop as I'll always be looking at Column B